# background-image height to properly scale down in css?

Tags: css, responsive-design, background-image

I have currently built a grid layout for my content and i want to use images inside a div column as the background. At first I placed an image with a class of "img-responsive inside the div columns and this works perfectly. Now i want to achieve the same effect but have the image as a background instead. I am having trouble getting my background-image height to scale with the width of the div. With the img-responsive class i have a 'width: 100%;' and 'height: auto;' how do i apply the same logic to a background-image? I can't set the div column class to height: auto; or have a max-height of N pixels because this displays nothing. Below is an example of my code, The top two divs are what what i want my background images to be like. Can anyone explain to me how i can achieve this?

```css
      body {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 30px 30px 5px 30px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        color: black;
        font-size: 1.2em;
      }
      section {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0px auto;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        padding: 30px;
        color: black;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .row {
        margin: 1% auto;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
      }
      .row::after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
      }
      .col {
        line-height: 0;
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-right: 1%;
        margin-top: 1%;
        margin-bottom: 1%;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .col:first-child {
        margin-left: 0px;
      }
      .col:last-child {
        margin-right: 0px;
      }
      .img-responsive {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }
      .col.col-6 {
        width: 47%;
        height: auto;
        border: 2px solid black;
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-right: 1%;
      }
      .col.col-6-bg {
        width: 47%;
        max-height: 1000px;
        min-height: 145px;
        min-height: 200px;
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-right: 1%;
        border: 2px solid black;
      }
      .img-bg {
        background-image: url("http://prasinostcharles.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/gallery-large_food_cod.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
      }
      @media (max-width: 766px) {
        section {
          width: 90%;
        }
        col {
          width: 80%;
          margin: 10px auto;
          padding: 0;
        }
        .col.col-6 {
          width: 98%;
          min-height: 141px;
          margin-left: 0;
          margin-right: 0;
        }
        .col.col-6-bg {
          width: 98%;
          min-height: 200px;
          margin-left: 1%;
          margin-right: 1%;
        }
      }
```

```html
<h2>Div with img</h2>
<div class="row">

  <div class="col col-6">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://prasinostcharles.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/gallery-large_food_cod.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="col col-6">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://prasinostcharles.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/gallery-large_food_cod.jpg">
  </div>

</div>

<h2> Div with img as bacground</h2>
<div class="col col-6-bg img-bg"></div>
<div class="col col-6-bg img-bg"></div>
```

Comment: use background-size: 100% auto; 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: I have tried this, but it's still not working properly. I want my col-6 div to automatically be the height of my background image if that makes sense?

Comment: That makes sense, but with pure css, there is no way to make the element that you are styling with a background automatically have the same height as its background-image. I would look into solutions that don't use background image, or set the height manually.

Comment: Dam! I've been trying to do this for hours xD. I have figured out a way but it's kind of pointless. I insert a blank png image into the div and then set the background to the image i want. But it's pointless considering i could just place the image i want in the div. But il take it as a solution haha! Thanks for your comments they have been helpful!

Comment: Good luck with your project.